# What is the model of this bike?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, frames

I am looking for the model of this bike. I'm considering buying it, but the owner doesn't know what brand/model it is.

The bottom tube seems to have lost the brand name, but on the front of the frame, there is a logo which looks like Cervelo. But the bike does not look like any cervelo frame I looked up.

Also from the wheels and derailleur I think the bike is from the 2000s.

[image: bike]

[image: logo]

Comment: I'd always be EXTREMELY wary of buying a bike from someone that doesn't know what it is.  Even more so in a case like this one where they bike has some relatively nice components fitted

Comment: Yes I agree, it is odd. But for second-hand entry level bikes, most people don't know much about their bike, especially when they bought it used themselves.
But anyway I think I will pass on it, to be safe.

Comment: A head-on shot of the front decal/badge would be quite helpful.  Sometimes you can even get a hit with Google images.

Comment: Age-wise, I'd guess the bike dates between 1990 and 2005 or so.

Comment: @Nathan this doesnt appear to be an entry level bike.  The ksyrium wheels probably retailed around $500 when new and the easton carbon fork suggests a bicycle higher up the range or an owner who cared for the bike and wanted to upgrade it.  This is the type of bike where i'd expect its owner to know every last detail of it.

Comment: @AndyP The wheels seems to be aksium not ksyrium. Regarding the easton fork, I don't know anything about it, but I found some used one around 100-150$, so I though it wasn't that big a deal.

Answer (score 7):

Bike decals do not just "get lost" - someone has put effort into removing branding and evidently all the paint.

I suspect there's no serial number, and no receipts or paperwork either.

Someone who can afford a fancy brand like a Cervelo generally doesn't need to sell a bike.

Finally, the poor thing has flat mountainbike pedals - that would be highly unusual for a road bike.

The Cervelo logo is pretty obvious - its either the full word or this one `e` with an accent char.  What I can see of the headtube badge looks nothing like this.

[image]

I'd suggest you walk away from this one.  If you do go ahead, consider that if it was "recovered" in the future you loose the bike and likely never see your payment.  There's always other bikes out there.

Comment: I’d be suspicious, but there are plenty of legal ways to end up with a bike without decals and without papers.

Comment: Regarding "Someone who can afford a fancy brand like a Cervelo generally doesn't need to sell a bike", these people would have already upgraded to carbon fiber and the aluminum one would be on second hand market.

Comment: @Michael - Yes, we regularly see pictures here of bikes which have been carelessly painted, obliterating the decals.

Comment: @Criggie - I agree on the removing branding part, it looks sketchy. For the flat vs clipless pedal argument, it is not uncommon on basic road bike (used for commuting for example).
But yeah, overall I guess it's safer to look for another one.

Comment: I really wouldn’t disregard it just because of the missing decals and unknown brand. It looks like a good entry level road bike.

Comment: People sometimes remove decals when repurposing as a commuter bike, to reduce the risk of theft. So it’s a possible explanation for why the bike got that way, although maybe not to the current owner.

Answer (score -2):

Did a reverse image search on the photo of the bike and it should be a

"2013 Specialized tarmac sport"

Have a look at the [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=specialized%20tarmac%20comp%202013)

As has already been said here - be careful if it has been "altered" in this way...

Comment: ...except that the frame looks nothing like the ones displayed in the search results.

Comment: Yeah, the photo in the above link looks nothing like the OP's picture.

Comment: Okay guys, Nathan asked about the brand/model. As we can see the search results are showing the right brand, style and model of the bike from the OP's picture.